# Android compatibility issue with small screens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, google-play

I have an issue with my android project in compatibility with a some devices, like LGE P-350, ZTE Kyivstar Shine(racer2) and Samsung galaxy mini. These devices are listed not supported and I can not find why this so far.

Next to the apk file in edit application it writes the following:

> API level: 7-16+ Supported screens: small-xlarge OpenGL textures: all

The supported devices list says these devices are not compatible but no further information.

These devices support API 8 or better, so that should not be the issue.

Supported screens says small-xlarge. I found that there is no smaller sceen size than "small" so I do not know why could that be an issue. The problematic devices however do have small screen size/density. In res I have many of the layouts and most of the drawable in -mdpi -ldpi and -hdpi folders optimized for smaller screens.

I added to my manifest just for trying the following but the problem was not resolved:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

My project also uses google maps libary and android-mapviewballoons, which I also have no idea why that would be an issue but I write it here just in case.

I ran out of ideas, I searched for solutions in the following links but so far no luck. Some ideas about what could be wrong would be really helpful.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Thanks,
Zoltán

Comment: have you tried <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"/>

Comment: Yes I have, it is written in the original post.

Comment: If you removed supports-screens and used compatible-screens instead and enumerated all the combinations, will it help? Here's an example - http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. Unfortunately your suggestion does not work for me because it is available at api level 9+, I am using  7 and can not afford to go higher.

Comment: The fact is also really annoying that I could install the app on these devices from SDK and they run smoothly without any problems. What the hell is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

It seems that Galaxy Mini does not support autofocus. Maybe the others also don't.